# how to use O_ASYNC and fcntl in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, asynchronous, fcntl

i want to use O_ASYNC option and when the pipe can read , 
the SIGIO's handler will run .

but the following code are not work . any one can help me ?

```
#!/bin/env perl
use Fcntl;
 $SIG{IO}= sub {
   print "catch SIGIO!\n";
};

my $flags=0;

open(FH,"-|","sleep 4 ;echo aaa") or die "$!";

fcntl(FH,F_GETFL,$flags) or die "$!";
fcntl(FH,F_SETFL,$flags | O_NONBLOCK | O_ASYNC) or die "$!";

sleep(5);

print  "complete\n";
```

my perl version is 5.16.1 , operation system is Redhat 5u4 ,kernel 2.6.18, x86_64

Comment: Does O_ASYNC on a FIFO work on your system in, say, C?

Comment: I write a C version, but It was also not work: can you give me a C example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Linux, you must both request asynchronous notification (O_ASYNC) and specify a recipient (F_SETOWN).  So, you need only add one line to your example to make it work:

```
#!/bin/env perl

use Fcntl;

$SIG{IO}= sub {
   print "catch SIGIO!\n";
};

my $flags=0;

open(FH,"-|","sleep 4 ;echo aaa") or die "$!";

fcntl(FH,F_GETFL,$flags) or die "$!";
fcntl(FH,F_SETFL,$flags | O_NONBLOCK | O_ASYNC) or die "$!";
fcntl(FH,F_SETOWN,0 + $$) or die "$!";  # <-- Note that we force $$ to be numeric

sleep(5);

print  "complete\n";
```

Running the above:

```
$ perl so-12640993.pl
catch SIGIO!
complete
```

Comment: Why use the fancy `"-|"` argument instead of a normal pipe open?  Good catch on nummifying `$$`, BTW.

Comment: @tchrist, re: `"-|"`, just copying the OP's fanciness.  Re: `0+$$`, thanks.

Comment: the default owner of a file is who ? is not the process who open it ?

Answer (score 1):

`SIGIO` based asynchronous IO is edge-triggered, not level triggered.

Before any filehandle will send you a `SIGIO` you must first "arm" it. To do that, you need to perform whatever is the operation - `sysread()` in this case - until you get an `undef`/`EAGAIN`. At that point the filehandle will now be armed for `SIGIO` and will send a signal when it is next read-ready. You can then read it until it yields `EAGAIN`, which will arm it once more.

Comment: This analysis is mistaken.  If I `open(F, '-|')` and have the child `for ('foo', 'bar') { say; sleep 2; } exit`, and the parent will get three SIGIOs without doing anything to `F` other than O_ASYNC/F_SETOWN.  [Example here](http://pastebin.com/CyjGJtEA), also under kernel 2.6.18.