# Stop processing when client has timed out with HTTP::Daemon

Tags: perl, timeout, http-daemon

Is there a way to have `HTTP::Daemon` somehow detect when the client has disconnected (for instance because of a timeout) and thereafter kill itself?

Right now, this is how I wrote my server:

```
my $response;
try {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die __TIMEOUT__ };
    alarm 180;
    &process_query;
    alarm 0;
    $response = new HTTP::Response(200);
}
catch {
    if ( $_ eq __TIMEOUT__ ) {
        $response = new HTTP::Response(504);
    }
    else {
        $response = new HTTP::Response(500);
    }
};
$client->send_response($response);
```

This just assumes that the client will have given up after 180 seconds, which may or may not be true. I would like to go on processing as long as the client keeps waiting for a response, but not longer.

Comment: @Miller, `process_query` does some heavy processing depending on the query parameters, which could take anything between a few seconds and a few hours. But I don't mind that, as long as the client is willing to wait politely. The problem with a server-based timeout is, if it's too low, a client might not be able to get its answer while it was prepared to wait, but if it's too high, my server may keep doing heavy calculation (and process additional incoming queries slower) for nought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it will not check the file descriptor as long as you are processing data (single threaded), so it will not detect the problem. I see the following options:

- Check from time to time inside `process_query` if the `$client` socket is readable using `IO::Select` or similar. Readable can be that the client closed the connection or that it send more data, e.g. HTTP pipelining. You can try to check with `recv` and `MSG_PEEK` if there are data or eof (e.g. client shutdown), but you will not be able to detect if the are more data followed by eof, because you first have to read the data before you get the eof.
- If you are on UNIX you can use a rarely used feature: with `fcntl($client,F_SETOWN,$$)` you can make the kernel send you a `SIGIO` signal if there is a new event on the `$client` socket. But the last time I've used this Perl did not handle it correctly and I had to work around it by explicitly calling the `fcntl`-syscall: `syscall(SYS_fcntl,fileno($client),F_SETOWN,$$);`. Once you set this up you can handle the `IO` signal like you do with `ALRM` right now.

In any case: an eof from the client means only, that the client will no longer write (end of request). It might still be willing to read your data (one-sided shutdown). You only get to know if the client closed for read to once you send data and get a `SIGPIPE`. There is no way around it, this is how TCP with BSD sockets work.

Comment: That worked! I picked the second option and was able to make it work using also [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12654701/2025742) It needed setting the `O_NONBLOCK` and `O_ASYNC` flags before the `F_SETOWN`, and `$$` had to be forced to numeric context with `0+$$`. Thanks!